# How is this 20square root3 here?

Tags: vectors, triangles, pythagorean-triples

[image]

The question that we are given a polygon on left on diagram with each side 20m. Then in the right side I made a triangle of ABC. I drew head and tail of the vector on my own. Angle I got between vector AB and BC is 60. Therefore I drew components of BC . Then the triangle (green colour) I considered as my triangle whose length AC I have to find.

My teacher got the answer 20$\sqrt{3}$. So what I did is that $20^2 + 10^2 + 10$$\sqrt{3}$ As sum of Base and perpendicular = $ H^2$

My sir answer is 20$\sqrt{3}$ but I am not getting the same answer.Where am I wrong ?

I have tagged vectors since I want to confirm whether the way I drew head and tail of vector and components is right or not.

Comment: It's $(20+10)^2 + (10\sqrt3)^2 = AC^2$.

Comment: Ohhh.Thanks @peterwhy

Comment: If by any chance , question becomes complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with trigonometry for vectors, only the magnitudes come into play.  As such, the *direction* of the vectors drawn do not make a difference in calculating magnitudes.

Now for your question, without drawing the outside right triangles, this problem can be solved by using the law of cosines $$c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\gamma,$$
where in your case, $a=b=AB=BC=20$, $c=AC$, and $\gamma=120^\circ$.  Just showing the math here:
\begin{align}
AC&=\sqrt{20^2+20^2-2(20)(20)\cos120^\circ}\\
&=\sqrt{800+400}\\
&=\sqrt{1200}\\
&=20\sqrt3.
\end{align}

Comment: Ok.So if I would have not drawn direction of vectors.Then , isn’t it that to find angle between two vectors or sides would be difficult

Comment: Wow.I didn’t know about this law.Amazing

Comment: I assumed the polygon was a regular hexagon which has internal angles of $120^\circ$.

Comment: So , does the remaining angles matter. Which maybe 30 and 30

Comment: Let’s say they are 20 and 40 or 10 and 50.Can we sue the same law

Comment: The unknown side length (in this case, $c$) must be opposite the known angle (in this case, $\gamma$).  For further reading, try [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines).

Comment: Thank you   . .

Answer (score 1):

$$\angle A=30^\circ\implies BD=10\implies 
AD= \sqrt{20^2-10^2}=10\sqrt{3}\implies AC=20\sqrt{3}$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much